# How to apply multi agent deep reinforcement learning to an environment with discrete action space

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Do you know or have heard about any cutting edge deep reinforcement-learning algorithm which can be successfully applied for discrete action-spaces in multi-agent settings?

I have been researching and I have found [MADDPG](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02275.pdf) and [Soft Q-learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09817.pdf) algorithms as the top ones in the state-of-the-art. They are mainly focused on environments with continuous action space. Although they can be applied to discrete action-space (e.g. MADDPG with gumbel softmax) it seems it is not what they are intended for (I have tried with MADDPG (w/ Gumbel softmax) achieving disastrous results...). In their corresponding papers they don't give a lot of details of how to use them in these settings.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for ai.stackexchange than stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to use gumbel softmax for discrete actions. The output of actor network give you probability for each action(for discrete action space), by applying a constraint that a_t ~ [0,1]. That can solve your problem.

Comment: Do you mean using a softmax in the output of the actor? I tried it but it doesn't work. I think the problem with this approach is that when you feed the critic in with the output of the softmax to calculate the gradient of the actor, as this output doesn't include the "sampling" factor, it just doesn't propagate the desired gradient... wdyt?

Comment: Your intuition can be right, while using softmax. But i haven't seen anyone using softmax at actor's output. Give it a try, without softmax.